# How to swipe to remove a label?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uigesturerecognizer, gesture, uipangesturerecognizer

How can I perform a swipe do remove effect like this one:

[image]

I'v tried using a UIPanGestureRecognizer but It didnt work.

This is how I set it up:

```
- (IBAction)handlePan:(UIPanGestureRecognizer *)recognizer {


    CGPoint translation = [recognizer translationInView:self.view];
    recognizer.view.center = CGPointMake(recognizer.view.center.x + translation.x,
                                         recognizer.view.center.y + translation.y);
    [recognizer setTranslation:CGPointMake(0, 0) inView:self.view];

}
```

in the view controller .h I had this method signature, and in the nib file I added the required connections.

Do you recommend some other way to accomplish this? or using a UIPanGestureRecognizer is the right way but I'm doing it wrong?

Thanks ahead!

Comment: You definitely need to use a UIPanGestureRecognizer, but your code never actually removes the label... You're trying to remove the label, right? Right now it looks like you're just trying to move it...

Comment: @LyndseyScott hey, yes I want to delete it just like this, with the animation (actually I really wanted to delete it with the effect of pulling it pulling it like 30% to the right and releasing so it will go back and disappear if you can help with this). I know that here i'm just trying to move it, I need to add the rest of the code and need help here, and even the moving is not working..from some reason the method is not getting called, i tried with breakpoint

Comment: Did you enable your label's user interaction property?

Comment: Yes i did enabled it

Comment: And did you add the UIPanGestureRecognizer programmatically or in the storyboard?

Comment: In the xib not programmatically

Comment: and I control dragged a connection from the pan gesture object to the view controller.h file and created an action method

Comment: The reason it's not moving is probably because you're resetting the translation to zero during each call to this method on its last line. But no matter what, it sounds like what you're trying to do is not at all reflected by your code yet...

Comment: So can you help me accomplish this? Please

Comment: If you come back with more code, I can help you fix it, but as it stands now, I'd basically be writing your code from scratch and I don't have time for that.

Comment: Yes but I don't know how to do it, I only know how to delete a cell like this but not a label, but I understand you dont have the time, anyway thanks. Even if you could tell me where should I go from here could help

Comment: To remove the label you have to do [self.label removeFromSuperview]; or [recognizer.view removeFromSuperView];

Comment: I think this can be done easier with a scroll view embedded in the view. You'll get the bounce as seen in the sample too. I'll whip up a sample and post here.

Comment: @HenryTKirk please do buddy :)

Comment: @HenryTKirk if you can not save details on setting up some of the connections to make sure I don't mess something up since I'm a beginner. thanks!!